# adding time to dates which is in dash format

Tags: python-2.7

I have a string variable

```
endDate='2017-08-13'
```

which is in Y-m-d format, I want to combine it with 'time'  :

```
datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date(endDate), datetime.time(23, 00))
```

I think I am missing str to date time conversion and format. Please correct my mistake.

Thank in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you need is `datetime.strptime`

see https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime
for general reference

and https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior
for details about the format string

```
from datetime import time, date, datetime
endDate = datetime.strptime('2017-08-13', '%Y-%m-%d')
endTime = time(23,0)
result = datetime.combine(endDate, endTime)
```

The result is:

```
>>> result
datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 13, 23, 0)
```